# How to find users in AD that belong to a group, and just get their SAMAccountName, and SID?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I just want a user to be able to type in a group name in a textbox, and return just their login name and their SID.

So far i have this, and that loads the users in the group but im unsure how to extract the login and SID.

```
 SearchResult result;
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();
            search.Filter = String.Format("(cn={0})", txtGroup.Text);
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectGUID");
            result = search.FindOne();


            StringBuilder userNames = new StringBuilder();
            if (result != null)
            {
                for (int counter = 0; counter <
                result.Properties["member"].Count; counter++)
                {
                    string user = (string)result.Properties["member"][counter];
                    userNames.AppendLine(user);

                }
            }
            lblResults.Text = userNames.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The propertie wich contains SID is called `objectSid`, and the propertie wich contain th login is `sAMAccountName` for the NT4 compatible version and `userPrincipalName`. You'd better work with @Virkkunen advice.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  /* Connection to Active Directory
   */
  DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://192.168.183.138:389/dc=societe,dc=fr", "administrateur", "pwd");

  /* Directory Search
   */
  DirectorySearcher dsLookForGrp = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
  dsLookForGrp.Filter = String.Format("(cn={0})", "yourgroup");
  dsLookForGrp.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
  dsLookForGrp.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
  SearchResult srcGrp = dsLookForGrp.FindOne();

  /* Directory Search
   */
  DirectorySearcher dsLookForUsers = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
  dsLookForUsers.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(memberOf={0}))", srcGrp.Properties["distinguishedName"][0]);
  dsLookForUsers.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
  dsLookForUsers.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSid");
  dsLookForUsers.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName  ");
  dsLookForUsers.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
  SearchResultCollection srcLstUsers = dsLookForUsers.FindAll();

  foreach (SearchResult sruser in srcLstUsers)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", sruser.Path);

    SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier((byte[])   sruser.Properties["objectSid"][0], 0);
    Console.WriteLine(sid.ToString());    

    foreach (string property in sruser.Properties.PropertyNames)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("\t{0} : {1} ", property, sruser.Properties[property][0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work better if you reverse your query:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf={0}))
```

This way you'll directly get back a list of users by using `FindAll`. Don't forget to add `sAMAccountName` etc into `PropertiesToLoad`.